# Does javac always compile the .java file to .class file at each time being called?

Tags: java, makefile, gnu-make, javac

When using GNU Make, the source file won't be compiled again if the source file is no newer than the already existed object file. I am wondering if this is also the behavior of javac? Or will javac always compile the source file without checking the existing class file?

Comment: You're comparing different classes of tool. The suitable comparison is between `javac` and `cc`, or between Make and Maven or Gradle (both of which will skip compiling unmodified files).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a javac *.java it will always recompile the java files in your current directory, or javac Test.java will always compile one file.

HOWEVER, if Test.java relies on other java files, they will be compiled to classes but the rules are different!

They will only be compiled if the source file has a newer date (And I'm sure there are other cases I'm not thinking of)

Perhaps this is the behavior you observed?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling for the first time:

[image]

Compiling one minute later (without modifying Test.java):

[image]

As you can see, the modification date of `Test.class` changes when compiling without modifying `Test.java`.

Answer (score 0):

She here:-

```
 javac  myclass.java
```

Each time you compile the file it will create a new myclass.class file. But tool like `mavan` first check whether original java file has been changed/modified or not. If not it will not ask `javac` to compile it again else it will compile the file. Hence in tool like `mavan` or tool like `eclipse` we have to ask for a clean build for compiling all the java files, else it will instruct `javac` to compile only modified java files.